# How to playback video youtube using mytoolkit in windows phone 8 silverlight

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, youtube-api

I building an youtube app, I used google youtube apis v3 and mytoolkit as following code:

```
  <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <player:MediaPlayer x:Name="player" AutoPlay="True" />
  </Grid>
```

code behind:

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
       if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
       {
            string videoId = string.Empty;
            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("videoId", out videoId))
            {
                 //Get The Video Uri and set it as a player source
                 var url = await MyToolkit.Multimedia.YouTube.GetVideoUriAsync(videoId, MyToolkit.Multimedia.YouTubeQuality.Quality480P);

                 if (url != null)
                    player.Source = url.Uri;

                  // MessageBox.Show(url.Uri.ToString());
                  player.Play();


            }
        }
        else
        {
             MessageBox.Show("You're not connected to Internet!");
             NavigationService.GoBack();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }

    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}
```

But **when the app run I cant playback selected video** ,how can I fix this error?

Comment: Did you try moving your code behind a button click like the example states? ( https://github.com/MyToolkit/MyToolkit/wiki/YouTube ) Just to be sure that it actually works. And if that works, I guess your example doesn't because you are handling everything in OnNavigatedTo. Maybe better to wait until the controls are loaded. So move the code to Page > loaded or player > loaded

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the right videoId, you can do something like this:

```
public Youtube()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     Loaded += Youtube_Loaded;
}

async void Youtube_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     try
     {
         string videoId = "iqjMRdev0FI";
         var url = await YouTube.GetVideoUriAsync(videoId, YouTubeQuality.Quality480P);
         player.Source = url.Uri;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
     }

}
```

Hope this helps.